Sharing QGIS project or interactive map with clients
I'm looking for a safe and secure way to share my QGIS project to different clients.
The information stored in the data files is sensitive. The user can't be allowed to modify it.
I've looked into password protecting my GPKG or project but this can't seem to be done. I'm thinking about creating WMS layers with my data and then sharing a project with my clients.
Do you have other ideas about how this could be done ?

By modifying, do you mean editing the original data files? Or do you wish that users could not make their own copies and modify them? Preventing the latter is hard.

QGIS is a good option. Part of it is the QGIS Server, which can be made accessible on a web server. Save your data on the server along with the project file, and it will render it at the client's request. Clients can connect to it through QGIS on their computers. Sharing only through WMS will only render the image of the map/project to the client so the editing is not possible.

I would add that it seems to be a use case for Lizmap (https://www.lizmap.com) + QgisServer to serve a webmapping application. This come with some configuration to go trough though.
Well any webclient + Qgis server and WMS info to show the map

Thanks, I didn't know about it. It seems a good option although hosting is a bit pricey

Modifications in a SQLite database like GeoPackage or SpatiaLite could be blocked with triggers. The following example blocks insert, update and delete for the table some_table:
CREATE TRIGGER block_insert_some_table
BEFORE INSERT ON some_table
BEGIN
    SELECT RAISE(FAIL, 'Inserts are not allowed on the some_table table');
END;

CREATE TRIGGER block_update_some_table
BEFORE UPDATE ON some_table
BEGIN
    SELECT RAISE(FAIL, 'Updates are not allowed on the some_table table');
END;

CREATE TRIGGER block_delete_some_table
BEFORE DELETE ON some_table
BEGIN
    SELECT RAISE(FAIL, 'Deletes are not allowed on the some_table table');
END;

But keep in mind: This is a soft "lock" and can be removed easily with basic knowledge about sqlite. The "lock" is removed by dropping the triggers:
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS block_insert_some_table;
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS block_update_some_table;
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS block_delete_some_table;

To sum up: This could be a solution for protection against accidental edits. Because the data could be exported in any other format. With that the "protection" would be lost.

I think your best bet with this would be to go through web map service, but another good option to consider would be arcgis online, in arcgis online you can share data with fine-grained permissions, including view-only settings but This option may involve licensing costs depending on your or your client’s AGOL account type.

If your data is in a PostgreSQL/PostGIS and this db instance is on the cloud, you could save the QGIS project into the PostgreSLQ db along with the data. This should allow external clients/users to open the QGIS project and see the maps and with PostgreSQL's rich user/group roles you could determine who can edit or view the individual map features.
